# upload image by user and display images in her/his profile if admin accept uploaded image to display

Tags: 7, users, media

I want the users to add their images; the administrator should be able to accept the images, which would then be visible on the user profiles.

I create the gallery using the help from https://www.drupal.org/node/1497058#comment-9552679.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried with Flag module? should match your needs

Comment: i'm new in drupal , can you give me a global view that i can know what should i do?

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1857668) about Flag module

Comment: thank you soo much zaporylie, it was soo helpfull, i solve this problem now i need i gallery that read all image in certain directory, do you know which module can i use?